# Virtual environment on PyCharm is orange

Tags: pycharm

My virtual environment on PyCharm is orange and I cannot get it to change to grey. All the folders in it are also an off color.

[image]

I am working on a 2013 Macbook Air.

Comment: That's virtual-env. In PyCharm (and other JB IDEs) temp folders are marked orange.

Answer (score 1):

It is by design. Virtual environment (`venv` in your case) is intended to be excluded (orange highlighting) as it is not a part of your project source code. Which also means you should not store any custom files inside it. Move them to the project root.